# How to find the PCs name in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

How would I find the name of the PC running my batch program on it?

I would like to find the name of a PC that is running my batch program and be able to store it as a variable.
Any help?

Comment: you can retrieve the hostname of a system from the cmd or powershell command line with `hostname`. you shouldn't need to store it as a var, just invoke it inline as you need it.

Comment: @FrankThomas - Why don't you provide this as (perhaps with a short example) an answer instead?

Comment: `hostname` is an exe, and while it outputs the machine name on console, it will be non-trivial to capture it in a batch file. Luckily, there is already an environment variable set, and available (`ComputerName`) to use on typical windows system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Vikas Gupta has answered, you can use the pre-defined `%COMPUTERNAME%` environment variable that already contains the computer name. From a practical stand point, this should be all you need.

However, it is possible for a batch file to over-write the value, so it is not guaranteed that the value be correct.

You can use WMIC to directly read the computer name.

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic computersystem get name'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set "compName=%%A"
```

The extra FOR loop eliminates unwanted carriage return characters that are an artifact of FOR /F interacting with the Unicode output of WMIC. With only one loop there is a carriage return at the end of each line that can cause problems.

Comment: is there a reason for using wmic instead of just calling `hostname`?

Comment: I thought of that after I wrote the answer. It certainly would be simpler. I'm no expert on these issues, but based on http://serverfault.com/q/260563/201695, I think host name and computer name are not guaranteed to be the same. But I think they are supposed to be the same under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 38):

On Windows, typically an environment variable is already set and available for you to use -

```
echo %ComputerName%
```

Comment: Which versions of Windows does this apply to?  (Worked for me in Windows 7.)

Comment: This variable is present at least all the way back to Windows NT.

Comment: interestingly enough though, it won't work in a powershell; only in cmd.exe. odd that.

Comment: Powershell has its own way of representing special things like Environment Variables... following works - `Get-Item Env:\ComputerName`

Comment: @VikasGupta You could just use `$env:computername` (case-insensitive too).

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can also use:

```
[Environment]::MachineName
```

Here the value comes from .Net so it avoids the issue of using `$Env:ComputerName`.

Comment: What's the issue of using `$Env:ComputerName`?